# Terraform Lifecycle to ignore SSH-Key in metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

When you use gcloud to ssh to an instance, it adds that ssh pubkey to the instance's metadata to let you in. Awesome.

Except, now terraform wants to remove that metadata because it's not in the .tf file. I don't care that it's not in the .tf file, I want terraform to ignore the SSH keys, and due to security concerns I can't control I'm not able to use project-wide SSH keys.

I know how to set a lifecycle policy that ignores *all* metadata, but we still want to be notified if the hostinit script changes, so I'm trying to find a way to only ignore the ssh keys metadata.

As you can imagine this is rather hard to get good Google results for, but I have tried.
There are a number of similar questions but they're resolved by enabling project wide SSH keys which I can't do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either ignore all meta data

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
 
  ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      metadata
    ]
  }
}
```

or just specific ones, here for example `metadata["sshKeys"]` (the syntax for map elements in `ignore_changes`)

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      metadata["sshKeys"]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You can find the details about lifecycle customization using [‘ignore_changes’](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#ignore_changes). You can also post your detailed query in HashiCorp [discussion forum](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/c/terraform-core/27) to reach out to the terraform community.

Comment: With Terraform v0.12.29 this worked for me: `ignore_changes = [metadata["sshKeys"]]`

Comment: As of 2021 and Terraform 1.x it's `ignore_changes = [metadata["ssh-keys"]]` for me.